# Proving that if the greatest lower bound property exists in a set then so does the least upper bound property.

Tags: real-analysis

let $A \subset R$ where $R$ denotes the real numbers. We are investigating whether the set $A$ has the GLB (greatest lower bound) property or not. In other words whether $inf A$ exists or not.

> Q : 
>   Prove that if $A \subset R$ and least upper bound property exists in A, so does the greatest lower bound property.

**My Approach:**

LUB existing implies that for every subset $A_i \subset A$ each $A_i$ has a least upper bound.

Corresponding to each $A_i \subset A$ let $S_i$ be the set of upper bounds for $A_i$. As given in the question, $min(S_i)$ exists. let $b_i = min(S_i)$. Clearly $b_i = inf (S_i)$ for each index $I$.

Now All I need to show that $S_i$'s can correspond to all subsets of $A_i$ Mainly : $\bigcup_{all \ I} S_i = P(A)$ where $P(A)$ is the set of all subsets of $A$. However I couldn't show it. Is it obvious? I need a rigorous proof. Will my proof be OK when I complete this part? Or should I just look for something simpler?

Thanks.

Comment: $A$ must be bounded below, no?

Comment: @MyGlasses Greatest lower bound property can not exist without $A$ being unbounded from below. The Hypothesis gives us that $A$ is bounded from below.